# Maximum number of hard drives in a build-your-own NAS solution

Tags: storage, network-attached-storage

My IT department has a bunch of older 160/320GB Drives. I'd like to use them in a build-your-own NAS device. What limitations exist in regards to the maximum number of drives that can be connected to typical commodity hardware that might be used in a situation like this?

**EDIT** 
okay I like to specify my question is

- what to search for to find a storage controller which can handle many drives. I simply cannot find the right search terms.

Comment: I edited out the part where you ask for a specific product and list a price. All shopping questions are off-topic here. Honestly, this question will probably still be closed, but maybe not.

Comment: Attaching "hundreds" of used, low capacity, low RPM, presumably IDE drives into a NAS array is an awful idea, however.  Yeah, you can do it, but you can also stick a fork into the electrical outlet... which actually sounds *less* painful.

Comment: To address your edit (the one that likely got this question closed), call your preferred hardware vendor. That's the kind of question that they get paid to answer.

Answer (score 4):

You can attach as many as your selected storage controller, port replicators/backplanes, and Operating System can handle.